# React Native Expo access VPN endpoint

Tags: react-native, expo, vpn

I´m developing an project using react native Expo that needs to fetch an JSON document, on a endpoint that is covered by an VPN connection using SSTP tunnel.

I have been developing on Android Emulator and iOS Simulator, with my computer configured on VPN connection and its been working fine with no problem at all, the app on the emulators can fetch the request url and get the json document.

When i try to use the tunnel or lan method to expose my app on real devices, the app its successfully installed but cannot fetch the url, it always says Http request throws Network Request Failed. Both are in the same network, there is any reason why this happen or any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging i finally found what i want. Basically all i needed to do was to expose my VPN Webservices connections by using ngrok or other program for the same purpose. The program will create a tunnel (HTTP and HTTPS) creating an hole on the firewall and a custom URL to access.

There are many ways to do the same, for me the ngrok was the best but this link help me a lot to understand: [How to call a locally hosted server from Expo?](https://dsinecos.github.io/blog/How-to-call-a-locally-hosted-server-from-expo-app)  and also the [ngrok documentation](https://ngrok.com/docs) and [How to Run Ngrok to Test & Share Your Local Development](https://www.jobsity.com/blog/how-run-ngrok-test-share-your-local-development)